# An open problem on special primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Conjecture:

Let $ p $ be a prime natural number.

Find all primes $ q\equiv1\left(\mathrm{mod}\: p\right) $, such that $ 2^{\frac{\left(q-1\right)}{p}}\equiv1\left(\mathrm{mod}\: q\right) $.

Is not the case $p=2$ answered by all odd primes $q$ for which the Legendre symbol is $(2/q)=1$?

Is this case also open?

Comment: The odd primes for which that Legendre symbol is 1 are precisely the primes $\pm1\bmod8$.

Comment: Is this considered "having found all such primes"? So the case $p=2$ is not open? Are the other cases open?

Comment: What would you consider to be "having found all such primes"? There are infinitely many of them, you're never going to write them all down, or even write down a useful formula that churns them out. Saying they are the primes $\pm1\bmod8$ is about as good as it gets. For $p=3$, you want 2 to be a cubic residue of $q$. I think the theorem for that says it happens if and only if $q=a^2+27b^2$ for some $a,b$ (see https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Cubic_residue). It may be that once $p$ is large enough, you really do have an open question.